# Gluon mobile - Compilation error when using a WebView

Tags: javafx, webview, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am new with Gluon Mobile so I decided to test the Hello Gluon samples with the Gluon maven plugin.
All samples works ok but If I want to use a javafx WebView,
mvn client:compile generate  a compilation error :

Warning: Aborting stand-alone image build. **com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: javafx.scene.web.WebView.** To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing type is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.

To reproduce the problem :
Platform : windows

In pom.xml of HelloGluon sample, I added the javafx-web dependency :

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
  <version>${javafx.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and I added one instruction in HelloGluonApp.java une the init) method :
WebView webView = new WebView();

then when I run mvn client:compile, the exception is thrown:
com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: javafx.scene.web.WebView.

**In the log javafx-base,javafx-controls and javafx-graphics are scanned but except javafx-web ????**

Scanning C:\Users\BEMAR.gluon\substrate\javafxStaticSdk\16-ea+gvm24\windows-x86_64\sdk\lib\javafx-base.jar

Scanning C:\Users\BEMAR.gluon\substrate\javafxStaticSdk\16-ea+gvm24\windows-x86_64\sdk\lib\javafx-controls.jar

Scanning C:\Users\BEMAR.gluon\substrate\javafxStaticSdk\16-ea+gvm24\windows-x86_64\sdk\lib\javafx-graphics.jar

Is it not yet supported or how should I add this jar in the configuration of the plugin ?

thanks for advance.

Comment: Did you add `javafx.web` as dependency? On mobile it should work.

Comment: i just started working with gluon-mobile and i have the same issue here. in my case i added javafx.web to the dependencies. maven target javafx:run work's fine.

Comment: Yes , I added it.

Comment: Yes , I added it. and the sample works well in a jvm , but the problem occurs when Gluon plugin compile the code for x86_64-microsoft-windows

Comment: I have the problem on linux (centos 8.3/amd64). "mvn -Pdesktop client:compile" (x86_64-linux-linux) builds successful but linking fails. And "mvn -Pandroid client:compile" (aarch64-linux-android) fails with the error above.

Comment: I have the problem on windows